# Is there a Kinfu version that runs with ROS on an Odroid?

Tags: untagged

I have a ROS-based robot that runs on an Odroid with a 3d Camera (Openni-based) and would like to use Kinfu (or something similar) on it. I'm not sure if the Mali-GPU is fast enough, but so far I didn't find an implementation that told specifically that it was used on an Odroid.

Does someone know such an implementation?

Comment: Could you define fast enough ? I guess that if you decrease the frequency at some point, the load will be reasonable for the Mali-GPU.

Comment: Several frames per second as a rough idea. But I could also downsample the pointcloud, but so far, I don't have a running implementation with which I could start experiments.